# How to put placeholder datetime-local

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I try to give default value to datetime-local. I try this code:

```
 <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="event.startdate" value="2016-10-09T15:38:00">
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me please.

Comment: set event.startdate value to the default value in your controller and it will showup here

Comment: i did it but the same thing , i get no result

Comment: Did you try @Patrick Ferreira answer? and are you seeing any error in browser console by setting start date in controller?

Comment: YEEAAH I TRY IT . I get this error

Comment: ` Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2016-10-09T15:38:00` to be a date`.  AAh , I forget to add ionic tag ,

Comment: I just saw your comments, maybe something with version of angular, which one do you use?

Comment: yeeaaah , mayy bee . I m using 1.5.3 angular version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should init your `$scope`, in that case `event.startdate`. You can do it with `ng-init` directive property or through `$scope` in your controller. 
Look demo below :

EDIT : updated to work with angular 1.5.3

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.event = {
    startdatefromcontroller: new Date('2016-10-09T15:38:00')
  };
});
```

```css
section {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
section label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  
  <section>
    <label for="startdatefromcontroller">Init from controller through $scope</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="event.startdatefromcontroller" id="startdatefromcontroller">
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: i try it but the same thing

Comment: As you can see, demo works, you should have a typo or some syntax issue

Comment: Oh, if your `event.startdate` is declared or updated by your controller code, the `ng-init` will be useless. Let me know how you create the `event` object

Comment: i don't  update  it in my controller.  I just put  `$scope.event={}`.

Comment: Well, I tryed with `$scope.event = {}` directly in the scope... no issues. That works well. I updated the code snippet with the 2 types of init.

Comment: I updated again the snippet, you should create a `Date` object with angular 1.5.3, that works now ;)